# Installation of extension in PHP

Tags: protocol-buffers, php-extension

I'm trying to install extension to PHP 5.3.6 on Ubuntu 11.10.
Extension is: `php-protobuf` from https://github.com/allegro/php-protobuf.

First I compiled it:  `phpize`, `./configure`, `make` then finally `sudo make install`. I got:

`Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php5/20090626/`

```
ziel@ziel:/usr/lib/php5/20090626$ ls -la protobuf.so 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 113599 2013-06-13 20:48 protobuf.so
```

In `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` I set:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir 
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php5/20090626/"
extension="/usr/lib/php5/20090626/protobuf.so"
```

But `php -m` says that that no `protobuf` extension is loaded.

[SOLVED]
I was doing everything OK. When I execute code via apache it worked. I realized that `php` from console need `php.ini` included.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how did you install it? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Just specify "protobuf.so" on the extension_dir INI entry. (check Apache error log file too)

About the php cli, check out where php.ini is being searched for.

```
php -i | grep .ini
```